# Nhibernate wrong alias in order-by annotation

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

I have a parent-child relationship set up inside one table "Fault" (on the left) and an associated entity "Review" in the table on the right.

```
-------------------------------    -------------------
|Id|Parent|Timestamp|Review_Id|    |Id|Note|Timestamp|
-------------------------------    -------------------
```

My hibernate mapping looks like that:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
    namespace="Models" assembly="DataAccess">

  <class name="Fault" table="Fault">
    <cache usage="read-write" />

    <id name="Id">
      <column name="Id" not-null="true" />
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="Parent" class="Fault" column="Parent_Id" cascade="all" />
    <one-to-one name="Review" class="Review" property-ref="Fault" />

    <bag name="SubFaults" lazy="true" order-by="Timestamp">
      <key column="Parent_Id" />
      <one-to-many class="Fault" />
    </bag>

    <property name="Timestamp" not-null="false" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I access the SubFaults collection, I get an Exception about an ambiguous column "Timestamp". Looking at the generated query reveals the problem quickly. In the end at the "ORDER BY Timestamp" no alias is used. Which leads to that very exception, since of course bot tables "Fault" and "Review" are joined together and both of them have a column "Timestamp". When I change this line: "" to "" then everything is doing fine. But I need the SubFaults to be ordered by **their** timestamp. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain the reason of putting `cascade="all"` to the `many-to-one` property?

Answer (score 1):

What could help, in any cases, when we are using the DB Engine *key-words*, is to wrap the column name. For SQL Server it is `[]`. So, try to use

```
<property name="Timestamp" column="[Timestamp]" not-null="false" />
```

*There is also more generic style as I remember with a sign like `, but for sql server the [] would do the job*

Comment: Just did some test, wrapping the timestamp column name in [] or `` resolve the problem.

Comment: Cool. great job. I do have experince with strange column names like "IdEntity" .. which is IDENTITY ... and the wrapping helps